# Istio: how do I setup HTTPS traffic between services on Minikube?

Tags: https, minikube, handshake, istio

I'm currently learning [Istio](https://istio.io/) and ran into a problem while trying to setup set up HTTPS traffic between containers on a local [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/) test cluster.

There are some related tasks in the Istio docs. Particularly the [https-overlay](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/https-overlay/) task. I managed to execute the first subtask (without sidecar on the querying container), but the [second one](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/https-overlay/#create-an-https-service-with-the-istio-sidecar-and-mutual-tls-disabled) fails with the following error when issuing a request to the nginx deployment from the sleep pod:

```
$ kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- curl https://my-nginx -k
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (35) error:1401E410:SSL routines:CONNECT_CR_FINISHED:sslv3 alert handshake failure
command terminated with exit code 35
```

I assume my setup is at fault but I can't really tell what's wrong (or how to debug). Can someone have a look and suggest a fix?

Setup steps are given below under *Setup*. Environment specs are shown below.

---

## Environment

### OS

macOS 10.13.6

### `kubectl` version

```
$ kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"12", GitVersion:"v1.12.3", GitCommit:"435f92c719f279a3a67808c80521ea17d5715c66", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-11-27T01:15:02Z", GoVersion:"go1.11.2", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

### `minikube` version:

```
 $ minikube version
 minikube version: v0.31.0
```

---

## Setup

`$ISTIO_HOME` should point to the location of the Istio installation.

### 1. Run Minikube + Istio Startup Script

**Warning:** This will stop and delete a running minikube instance.

```
#! /bin/bash
minikube stop;
minikube delete;
minikube start \
  --memory=8192 \
  --cpus=4 \
  --kubernetes-version=v1.10.0\
  --vm-driver=virtualbox; 
kubectl apply -f $ISTIO_HOME/install/kubernetes/helm/istio/templates/crds.yaml 
kubectl apply -f $ISTIO_HOME/install/kubernetes/istio-demo.yaml
# Set docker registry to minikube registry
eval $(minikube docker-env);
```

### 2. Run HTTPS Test Setup Script

Wait until the Istio pods are either running or completed and then

```
#! /bin/bash
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /tmp/nginx.key -out /tmp/nginx.crt -subj "/CN=my-nginx/O=my-nginx"
kubectl create secret tls nginxsecret --key /tmp/nginx.key --cert /tmp/nginx.crt
kubectl create configmap nginxconfigmap --from-file=$ISTIO_HOME/samples/https/default.conf
kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f $ISTIO_HOME/samples/https/nginx-app.yaml)
kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f $ISTIO_HOME/samples/sleep/sleep.yaml)
```

### 3. Issue Request To Nginx From Sleep Pod

Wait for both pods to start running and then run

```
kubectl exec $(kubectl get pod -l app=sleep -o jsonpath={.items..metadata.name}) -c sleep -- curl https://my-nginx -k
```

According to [the subtask](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/https-overlay/#create-an-https-service-with-the-istio-sidecar-and-mutual-tls-disabled) description, we should see the nginx landing page, but instead the error shown above (exit code 35, handshake failure) is returned.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are hitting this bug https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/7844 which is still open

Comment: I don't think so, the setup I'm running does not enable mutual TLS (the installation file `$ISTIO_HOME/install/kubernetes/istio-demo.yaml` does not do that).